# Google - Save to drive button curropts pdf file

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

So I am using [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) in my app to save files directly to user's google drive on button click. I have followed every instruction carefully and everything was working fine `until we uploaded a PDF File or and DOC | DOCX file with an Image or a table with it!.`

- First issue, when I click on Save to Drive button for a pdf file, the file gets uploaded to drive but it is corrupted. I am unable to preview/open file in google drive or even after downloading file from google drive to my system.
- Second issue is, when I upload a DOC file with some text  in it, the file gets uploaded, I see it in the google drive and when I open the file in drive it does not open at all, no preview and after I download the file to my system and open it, I see blank document.
- Third issue the last one, when I upload a DOCX file with table/image in it, as before, the file gets uploaded to the drive, I see it in it, and no preview as before. Surprisingly when I download the file to the system, sometimes the file open and some times it doesnt. But, when it opens table outlines are gone, image is half or any other issue appears.

I would like to know what might be causing this issue, because we have tried new files, new pdfs new doc docx file, because we thought, out files might have been corrupted. But nothing gives a positive result.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @noogui I gave link in the question and I am using the exact same code. Here it is again! https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive

Same div and same data field with my values.